# Ошибка Callback JNA

Tags: java, delphi, jna

Столкнулся с ошибкой вывода в Java. При вызове callback'a выплёвывает следующее сообщение

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
JNA: error while handling callback exception, continuing    
Exception in thread "main" JNA: error while handling callback exception, continuing
```

При вызове процедуры происходит передача не маленького объема данных (около 20к. строк), после определенной строки начинает сыпать вышеуказанными предупреждениями. Пытался очищать память после вызова, вызывать отдельно и т.д. 
Ниже приведён код структуры, callback'a и вызова самой функции.

```
public static class TTransactionInfo extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference{
            public short Size = 279;
            public short Kind;
            public long Summa;
            public short RestCode;
            public double LogDate;
            public byte UnitNum;
            public int CheckNo;
            public byte[] Comment = new byte[254];

            @Override
            protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
                return Arrays.asList("Size", "Kind", "Summa", "RestCode", "LogDate", "UnitNum", "CheckNo", "Comment");}


            public TTransactionInfo(){}

            public TTransactionInfo(short Size){
                this.Size = Size;
                new Memory(Size);
            }
        }

public interface GetTransactions extends Callback {
       default void callback(int account, double datetime, TTransactionInfo transact) {
          //здесь выполняется заполнение списков, ошибка появляется даже при отсутствии действий в этом блоке.
       }
}

boolean GetAllTransactions(double dateFirst, double dateLast, GetTransactions transaction);
```

Далее вызываю в методе main следующим образом

```
final static CscLink myLib = (CscLink) CscLink.INSTANCE;
myLib.GetAllTransactions(dates, dates, transact);
```

Ниже приведу фрагменты кода из delphi

```
type
  TTransactionInfo = packed record
    Size      : Word;    // Size of TTransactionInfo - заполнить перед вызовом
    Kind      : Word;    // 0-оплата 1-скидка 2-бонус 3-потраты гостя
    Summa     : Comp;    // сумма в копейках
    RestCode  : Word;    // код ресторана
    LogDate   : Integer; // дата чека (0 -> 30/12/1899)
    UnitNum   : Byte;    // номер кассы
    CheckNo   : Integer; // номер чека
    Comment   : Array[0..255] of Char; //комментарий - для ручных транзакций
  end;

type
  {процедура обратного вызова для перечисления транзакций}
  TEnumTransactions = Procedure( Account: Integer; When: TDateTime; const Info: TTransactionInfo ); stdcall;

{перечисление всех транзакций, результаты возвращаются через процедуру Proc}
Function GetAllTransactions( DateFirst, DateLast: TDateTime; Proc: TEnumTransactions ): BOOL; stdcall;
```

Comment: Причём до 18000 (+- 10-30 строк) выводит нормально (каждый раз по разному количество). После начинает сыпать ошибкой, указанной выше. Добавил проверку на null структуры `TTransactionInfo`, но ничего не изменилось...

Comment: Но, хочу ещё подметить, после ошибок выполнение кода продолжается согласно последующим операторам вывода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем всё было довольно просто в решении, но надо было прошерстить очень много документации и вариаций решения всего действия. Так как моя библиотека закрытая и довольно старая Callback нужно объявить как:

```
public static class TEnumTransactions implements StdCallCallback{
     public void callback (int account, double datetime, TTransactionInfo transact) {
         //код исполнения
     }
}
```

В общем то и вся суть. После имплементации `StdCallCallback` все ошибки ушли в небытие.